# Как разделить объект в массиве numpy на несколько?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, python-3.7

Есть массив:

```
[    0     1    10    11   100   101   110   111  1000  1001  1010  1011
  1100  1101  1110  1111 10000 10001 10010 10011 10100 10101 10110 10111
 11000 11001 11010 11011 11100 11101 ]
```

Как эти пробелы заменить на много массивов, вот так:

```
[[0], [1], [10], [11], [100], [101], [110], [111], ...]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```py
arr = [    0     1    10    11   100   101   110   111  1000  1001  1010  1011
  1100  1101  1110  1111 10000 10001 10010 10011 10100 10101 10110 10111
 11000 11001 11010 11011 11100 11101] # Запятые лень проставлять, простите. Представьте, что они там есть.
arr.shape = (len(arr), 1)
```

Если не получится, попробуйте поменять `len(arr)` и `1` местами.

А ещё лучше:

```py
arr = [    0     1    10    11   100   101   110   111  1000  1001  1010  1011
  1100  1101  1110  1111 10000 10001 10010 10011 10100 10101 10110 10111
 11000 11001 11010 11011 11100 11101] # Запятые лень проставлять, простите. Представьте, что они там есть.
arr.reshape((len(arr), 1))
```

Если не получится, совет аналогичный тому, что сверху.